# Why product use more memory than record?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

According to this presentation (http://oud.ocaml.org/2012/slides/oud2012-paper13-slides.pdf, PDF page 4), the following two data structures use different amount of memory

```
type t1 = { f1: float; f2:float};;
type t2 = (float * float);;
```

And t1 use less memory than t2, can anybody explain to me why is this the case?

Comment: `float * float` does not uniformly use more memory than records/arrays. On a 32-bit architecture, `let zero = 0.0 in (zero, zero)` uses less memory than `{ f1 = zero ; f2 = zero }`

Comment: @PascalCuoq, that's an interesting riddle! Will you post the answer, why it is so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

19.3.3 of http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html#sec425 says:

> Arrays of floating-point numbers (type float array) have a special, unboxed, more efficient representation. These arrays are represented by pointers to blocks with tag `Double_array_tag`.

This is introduced to handle big float arrays efficiently, but this applies also to record types only with floats.

https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/memory-representation-of-values.html is also a very good documentation which explains the internal value representation of OCaml.

Comment: Clean and well documented answer, bravo!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to camlspotter answer a few clarification notes:

1. In general records, arrays and tuples use the same amount of memory.
2. Some compound data structures using `float`s are exceptions. By default, each float is boxed, i.e., represented not as immediate value, but as a pointer to the allocated double precision floating point value. OCaml optimizes float records and arrays to store data directly, without double boxing.
3. This doesn't work for polymorphic records, e.g., `float ref`, that is underneath the hood is a record of type `a ref = {mutable contents : 'a}` still occupies extra amount of space, i.e., it is a pointer to a record, that contains a pointer to the word. But, if you define, `type float_ref = {mutable float_contents : float}` this would be a pointer to a record that contains directly a float value.